# Why is gcc resolving the address of a string during compilation?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, arm, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to do some bare metal programming on a Raspberry Pi 3B.  I still have not figured out the correct memory addresses for the UART controls so please just ignore those. I am experiencing a strange compilation issue though.

Here is the code I am trying to compile (not link):

```
void pstr(char* str) {
    unsigned int* AUX_MU_IO_REG = (unsigned int*)0x7E215040;
    unsigned int* AUX_MU_LSR_REG = (unsigned int*)0x7E215054;
    while (*str != 0) {
      while (!(*AUX_MU_LSR_REG & 0x00000020)) {
      }
      *AUX_MU_IO_REG = (unsigned int)((unsigned char)*str);
      str++;
    }
    return;
}
signed int kmain(unsigned int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) {
    char* text = "Test Output String\n";
    unsigned int* AUXENB = (unsigned int*)0x7E215004;
    *AUXENB = 0x00000001;
    pstr(text);
    return 0;
}
```

My addresses are not correct and invalid, but that is not the point.  For some reason, the string "Test Output String\n" is being resolved to an address in the object file.

It is being compiled with the command:

```
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -O2 -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mlittle-endian -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-stack-check -fno-stack-protector src/kernel/base.c -c -o src/kernel/base.o
```

Interestingly, it doesn't happen if I compile with "-O0".

Here is what it looks like with "-O2" using "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump -d ./src/kernel/base.o":

```
0000000000000040 <kmain>:
  40:   d28a0a80    mov     x0, #0x5054                 // #20564
  44:   f2afc420    movk    x0, #0x7e21, lsl #16
  48:   d28a0084    mov     x4, #0x5004                 // #20484
  4c:   f2afc424    movk    x4, #0x7e21, lsl #16
  50:   b9400000    ldr w0, [x0]
```

It crashes at "ldr w0, [x0]" because the address 0x7e215054 is not valid.  I just don't know why the compiler would even be putting that there.  It should be symbol to the data in .rodata so that it can be placed in the correct location by my linker script.

Comment: Isn't the compiler just accessing `*AUX_MU_LSR_REG`? That's set to `0x7E215054`.

Comment: Interesting.  That does seem to be the address it is accessing, but it shouldn't be doing that in the kmain function.

Comment: You think that he optimizations are causing gcc to move parts of one function to another?  I did not think gcc would dare cross that line.

Comment: Especially since it would cause such unexpected behavior if the function linked to and called from a separately compiled program.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/s4e8es It looks like `pstr` is getting fully inlined into kmain. If you use `-Os` instead of `-O2`, it won't inline and then the assembly would look more like what you expect.

Comment: @EchelonX-Ray: Inlining functions is an extremely common optimization and gcc will absolutely "dare" to do it.  It shouldn't change behavior at all; the compiler will also emit an out-of-line copy of the function in case it gets called from separately compiled modules.  Anyway, the cause of the crash is your code itself; you're explicitly asking for a load from `0x7E215054`, and you said yourself it's probably invalid.  All that's changing is where that code resides, which affects your debugging but not the overall behavior.